# Javascript on Superuser...

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

Is anybody else experiencing no-javascript on Super user?

No ability to add comments. No ability to see live-preview of markdown. No ability to run any jQuery code from Greasemonkey...

Answer (score 4):

I think you're probably experiencing what [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/firefox-trouble) had. Just hard refresh and it should be fixed.

Comment: That might have sufficed. I can't verify it though as I already went the long route :(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry JS, I think your alone on this one. Did you maybe break something with one of those awesome scripts of yours?

Answer (score 1):

I think I had accidentally set something in a site-preference. Deleting browsing history fixed it...very strange.